# SQL BigQuery Aggregation depending on conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am not sure how to solve this problem through an SQL query.
Imagine you have a table like this one:

| user_id | timestamp | quantity1 | quantity2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021/01/10 | 10 | 0 |
| B | 2021/01/17 | 10 | 0 |
| A | 2021/01/19 | 1 | 12 |
| B | 2021/01/25 | 10 | 8 |
| A | 2021/01/27 | 2 | 8 |

Now I want to aggregate by performing an ordered difference between quantity 1 and quantity 2.

So by a simple group by and sum I would have this result:

| user_id | result |
| --- | --- |
| A | -7 |
| B | 12 |

However what I want is that whenever the next intermediary sum is smaller than 0, then that sum is set to 0 before aggregating the next quantity.

In this case I would like to keep B = 12, but A instead should be:

First aggregation: (10-0)

Second aggregation: 10 + (1-12) = -1

Now since this is a negative result, it should be set to 0.

Third aggregation: 0 + (2-8) = -6

And if there was another entry, a negative previous aggregation should always start from 0.

I hope it was clear.

Anybody knows how to do this in SQL?

Comment: then why -7 in your desired output?

Comment: Third aggregation: 0 + (2-8) = -6

Comment: -7 is not my desired output, the desired output is -6. Which means that the second aggregation as it is negative (-1) goes to 0.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
declare result, delta, count int64;
declare id, prev_id string;
create temp table results as (select * from (select '' as user_id, 0 as result) where false);
create temp table your_table as (
  select 'A' user_id, '2021/01/10' timestamp, 10 quantity1, 0 quantity2 union all
  select 'B', '2021/01/17', 10, 0 union all
  select 'A', '2021/01/19', 1, 12 union all
  select 'B', '2021/01/25', 10, 8 union all
  select 'A', '2021/01/27', 2, 8 
);
set (count, result, delta, prev_id) = (0, 0, 0, '');
for record in (select * from your_table order by user_id, timestamp) do
  if record.user_id != prev_id  and prev_id != '' then 
    insert into results values(prev_id , result + delta);
    set result = 0;
  end if;
  set prev_id = record.user_id;
  set result = result + record.quantity1 - record.quantity2;
  if result < 0 then set (result, delta) = (0, result); else set delta = 0; end if;
end for;
insert into results values(prev_id , result + delta);
select * from results;
```

with output (in temp table `results`)

[image]

Obviously, instead of creating temp table `your_table` - you should just use you real table

Also, note use of just introduced (earlier today) [FOR...IN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#for-in) Loop

Comment: have you tried?